# Поиск элемента в определенном диапазоне std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, find

Для решения задачи мне нужно искать определенное число в `vector<int>`.

Но не во всем векторе целиком, а среди элементов, индексы которых находятся в диапазоне `[bufa; bufb)`.

Я попробовал сделать это через `std::find`, но получил ошибку.

Вот мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

vector<int> a;

int main()
{
    int n, q, bufa, bufb,temp;
    bool boo;
    char s;
    
    cin >> n >> q;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> temp;
        a.push_back(temp);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i];
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < q; y++)
    {
        cin >> s >> bufa >> bufb;
        
        if (s == '!')
        {
            a[bufa - 1] = bufb;
        }
        else
        {
            auto g = &a[bufa-1];
            auto h = &a[bufb-1];
            
            cout << endl;

            for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
            {
                
                if (find(g, h, i) == a.end()) // сделать поиск с элемента bufa до bufb
                {
                    cout << i<<endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio ругается на строку `if (find(g, h, i) == a.end())`:

> ```
> error C2679: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type
> ```

На всякий случай, вот полное условие задачи:

> Диме не дарили массив `a`, состоящий из `n` целых чисел на день рождения, он не покупал его, не находил на улице, а он у него просто есть и всегда был, и Диме не очень-то и интересно откуда.
>
> Дима не играет с массивом, не дарит его Пете, не режет на кусочки и не стремится его уничтожить.
>
> Дима просто выполняет операции двух видов со своим массивом:
>
> - `? l r` — узнать MEX мультимножества `{al, al+1, . . . , ar}`
> - `! i x` — присвоить `ai` значение `x` `(0 ⩽ x ⩽ n)`
>
> MEX мультимножества чисел `{a1, a2, . . . , ak}` — это минимальное целое `t ⩾ 0` такое, что `t ̸= ai` для всех `1 ⩽ i ⩽ k`.
>
> На самом деле, Диме не очень нравится выполнять операции двух видов со своим массивом.
>
> Диму волнуют лишь результаты операций первого типа. Помогите Диме и напишите программу, которая выполнит операции за него.
>
> **Формат входных данных**
>
> Первая строка содержит два целых числа `n` и `q` `(1 ⩽ n ⩽ 500 000, 1 ⩽ q ⩽ 250 000)` — размер массива, который есть у Димы и количество операций, соответственно.
>
> Вторая строка содержит `n` целых чисел `ai` `(0 ⩽ ai ⩽ n)` — массив Димы до начала операций.
>
> Каждая из следующих `q` строк содержит описание одной операции в формате, описанном выше.
>
> Гарантируется, что суммарно Дима сделал не более 50 000 операций изменения массива.
>
> Элементы массива пронумерованы, начиная с `1`.
>
> **Формат выходных данных**
>
> Для каждой операции первого типа выведите одно целое число — MEX соответствующего мультимножества.
>
> Ответы на запросы выводите в порядке, в котором они заданы во входных данных.
>
> **Пример**
>
> Ввод:
>
> ```
> 6 8
> 4 1 0 2 2 3
> ? 1 6
> ? 4 6
> ? 2 5
> ? 2 6
> ! 3 3
> ? 1 6
> ! 4 0
> ? 1 6
> ```
>
> Вывод:
>
> ```
> 5
> 0
> 3
> 4
> 0
> 5
> ```

Answer (score 2):

- Во-первых, у вас итераторы для поиска явным образом сделаны указателями:

  ```
  auto g = &a[bufa-1];
  auto h = &a[bufb-1];
  ```

  Это значит, что и `find(g, h, i)` будет тоже возвращать указатель. А вы этот указатель пытаетесь сравнивать с `a.end()`, который является `std::vector<int>::iterator`. Кто вам сказал, что это сравнимые типы?

  Вас, по-видимому, подвело наивное верование в то, что итераторы в векторе являются указателями. Но этого вам никто не обещал и не гарантировал.
- Во-вторых, при чем здесь вообще `a.end()`? В случае безуспешного поиска функция `std::find()` возвращает *конец входного диапазона*, т.е. в вашем случае она вернет `h`. Она в принципе не может вернуть никакого `a.end()`, ибо про `a` и слыхом не слыхивала.

В терминах указателей ваш код будет выглядеть так

```
auto g = &a[bufa-1];
auto h = &a[bufb-1];
...
if (find(g, h, i) == h)
```

Comment: в третьих решение неверное

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: Почему неверное? Оно "лобовое" и неэффективное, но ничего принципиально неверного я там не вижу.

Comment: Диме не дарили массив a, состоящий из n целых чисел... а он у него просто есть и всегда был. В решении берется пустой вектор и добавляется в конец  вводимые числа(это означает дарить Диме массив),   плюс лишные заголовочные файлы, лишные обьявленные обьекты, не  выведено значение при  if (s == '!')... Я имел ввиду все это, не  говоря о неэффективности. Сама логика правильна, но задача то тоже тривиальна!...

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: Как правильно реализовать на языке С++ концепцию "не дарили, а просто есть и всегда был" я не знаю. Что же касается тривиальности задачи... "Найти минимальное натуральное, отсутствующее в массиве целых" - популярная олимпиадная задача начального уровня, но не каждый может ее красиво решить.